# Is it possible a method with the name of a number in ruby?

Tags: ruby

This works:

```
if 1
    if 1
    elsif 2
    elsif 3
    end
end
```

But this produces a syntax error: unexpected '(', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'. I'm trying to execute the method `1`.

```
if 1
    if 1()
    elsif 2
    elsif 3
    end
end
```

I don't know what I should assume based on the error. That something earlier in the code is causing a problem? Or something later in the code is causing a problem?

Comment: Why do you add parentheses after `1`? They have no functionality.

Comment: let's say it's a function

Comment: But `1` is _not_ a function, nor can it ever be a function.

Answer (score 6):

When you write

```rb
1()
```

it is the syntax for calling a method named `1`.

But `1` is not a legal method name in Ruby, method names cannot start with a number.

If you had a method `foo` in scope, then you could write `foo()` in the place where you wrote `1()`, but it's superfluous to include the parens, as they are the wrappers for the method's arguments, and you are not passing any arguments.

`1` is interpreted by ruby as an integer, if you open an irb session and type `1()` you'll see the same error message that you saw "syntax error, unexpected '('", it has nothing to do with the fact that it's the condition on an `if` statement. This works fine:

```rb
def foo
  true
end

if foo()
  puts "hooray"
else
  puts "boo"
end
```

Comment: See the [Ruby Method Names](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Names) documentation.

Comment: I should not have called it 1. I was trying to make the minimal code. Actually it is a function, and If I pass an argument, I get the same result. Should I edit the question to reflect this?

Comment: @stephen definitely.

Answer (score 1):

1. Methods starting with numbers in ruby are not allowed.
2. You should not define a method with the name of a number.
3. It is not necessary to use parentheses in ruby to execute methods.

   If you don't pass arguments:

   ```rb
   some_method
   ```

   If you pass some arguments:

   ```rb
   some_method 'white'
   ```